# Extending modules in module pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I trying to use the module pattern with JS. But when I call `HM.init()` in the console, it says `undefined`. It's like `this.carousel` doesn't exist at all. Why is that?

JS:

```
(function(window, $){

    var HM = (function (HM) {

        HM.init = function(){
            this.carousel.init();
        }

        return HM;

    })(HM || {});

    window.HM = HM;

    $(function(){
        console.log(HM.init()); // this doesn't work
    });


})(window, jQuery);

//Extending module (this is supposed to be in another file)
(function(window, HM, $){
    HM.carousel = {
        init: function(){
            return 'initialise HM';
        }
    }
})(window, HM, jQuery);.
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it prints `undefined` is because `HM.init` doesn't return anything (no `return` statement, so it defaults to returning `undefined`).

Either you want to add `return` before the call to `this.carousel.init()`, like so:

```
...
HM.init = function(){
    return this.carousel.init();
}
...
```

...or you want to use `console.log` instead inside your `HM.carousel.init` function, if you want to print 'initialise HM' to the console:

```
...
HM.carousel = {
    init: function(){
        return 'initialise HM';
    }
}
...
```

(the return value in itself isn't a good debugging tool, so it probably makes more sense to print it with `console.log`.)

Comment: Thank Jonas for your response. I have updated the code but it's still doesn't work. Check out the code.

Comment: Right; the problem is that `HM.init` doesn't return anything.  `return this.carousel.init()` inside `HM.init` should work, at least it does for me.  By replacing with `console.log` I meant that you can change `return 'initialise HM` to e.g. `console.log('initialise HM')` (assuming it's only debugging output, and you don't actually want to return that). Sorry for the confusion :P

Comment: Thanks again, but in this project this code is meant to be the core where all other modules will be initialised, so doing return for each and every module is a bit messy. For example, a carousel module will be created as well a tab, accordion, and so on... So doing return for each of them is weird, unless I'm clueless of course.

Comment: Hence why you probably want `console.log` for debugging instead. The code itself works, but you think it doesn't because it prints `undefined`. The reason `undefined` is printed is simply because nothing is returned from the function you called. The string that you *do* return ('initialise HM') is being thrown away, since it isn't stored anywhere.